# Draw ideal symmetric css border with border-radius

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to draw a border with `border-radius: 8px;`. It perfectly draws symmetrical border without **border-radius** but messed up with it. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('border')[0].classList.add('animate-border');
},100)
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

.main-container {
  position:absolute; 
  top:50%; 
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 460px; 
  background: ;
}

.border:before {
  border:2px solid black;
 border-radius: 8px;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 0;
 border-left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(0) rotate(0);
    
}

.border.animate-border:before {
 opacity: 1;
 height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: opacity 0s ease,width 0.5s ease, height 0.5s 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotateZ(0) rotate(0);
}

.border:after {
  border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 8px;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotateZ(0) rotate(0);
}

.border.animate-border:after {
 opacity: 1;
 height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0s 1s ease,width 0.5s 1s ease, height 0.5s 1.5s ease;
  transform: rotateZ(0) rotate(0);
}
```

```html
<div class='main-container border'></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  background: white;
}

.main-container {
  position:absolute; 
  top:50%; 
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 460px; 
  background: ;
}

.border:before {
  border:2px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(0) rotate(0);

}

.border.animate-border:before {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: opacity 0s ease,width 0.5s ease, height 0.5s 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotateZ(0) rotate(0);
}

.border:after {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotateZ(0) rotate(0);
}

.border.animate-border:after {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0s 1s ease,width 0.5s 1s ease, height 0.5s 1.5s ease;
  transform: rotateZ(0) rotate(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you may apply `box-sizing: border-box` in all elements (and pseudo-elements) to make the alignment easier. It makes the browser count the border on width and height calculation. That solves your misalignment problem.

Second, since you're resizing the element, the rounded corners get stretched in the middle of the animation. I see no easy way prevent that from happening. But you can disguise it by also animating the `right` property of the `:after` pseudo-element, like I did below. That and a faster timing may get you there with your animation.

BTW, it would be more performant if you animated `transform: scaleX(...) scaleY(...)` instead of width and height, because they're GPU accelerated.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('border')[0].classList.add('animate-border');
},100)
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

*, *:before, *:after { /* Applies to ALL elements and pseudo-elements */
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.main-container {
  position:absolute; 
  top:50%; 
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 160px; 
  background: ;
}

.border:before {
  border:2px solid black;
 border-radius: 8px;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 0;
 border-left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(0) rotate(0);
    
}

.border.animate-border:before {
 opacity: 1;
 height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: opacity 0s ease,width 0.5s ease, height 0.5s 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotateZ(0) rotate(0);
}

.border:after {
  border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 8px;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 6px; /* a little offset to hide the squared edge */
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotateZ(0) rotate(0);
}

.border.animate-border:after {
 opacity: 1;
 height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0; /* the wanted right position */
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0s 1s ease,width 0.5s 1s ease, height 0.5s 1.5s ease,right 1s 1s ease; /* Animated 'right' so it slowly gets back to its position */
  transform: rotateZ(0) rotate(0);
}
```

```html
<div class='main-container border'></div>
```

PS.: I changed the box height to make it fit inside the snippet here.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify properties below to pseudo elements because they are position absolute

Add **top:0** to **.border:before** css and add **left:0** to **.border:after** css

Comment: Thank you but this won't fix it.